# Laravel 4 Redirect to Route with Array

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have an issue in my laravel app.

I want to sent an array to another route.

here is the code. 
Controller:

```
 $emparray =[
    'fname'=>Input::get('efname'),
    'lname'=>Input::get('elname'),
    'dob'=>Input::get('edob'),
    'reg_date'=>date('Y-m-d'),
    'email'=>Input::get('eemailaddrs'),
    'gender'=>Input::get('gender'),
    'mobile'=>Input::get('emobile'),
    'p_addrss'=>Input::get('epaddress'),
    'c_addrss'=>Input::get('ecaddress'),
    'quals'=>Input::get('quali'),
    'pdfname'=>$pdfname,
    ];

   return Redirect::to('print-view',$emparray);
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('print-view/{$emparray}', array('as'=>'print-view','uses'=>'EmployeeController@PrintView'));
```

Final Controller.

```
public function PrintView($emparray)
{
    return $emparray;
}
```

I Can't get the successful output. Is there any issues with my code.?

Getting error like **"The HTTP status code "1" is not valid."**
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Use Redirect::to('print-view')->with($emparray);

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it like this ,if you would check the `to` method you would see this - 

    `public function to($path, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
    {
        $path = $this->generator->to($path, [], $secure);
        return $this->createRedirect($path, $status, $headers);
    }`

so basically you send the `status` parameter an array. to send parameters you will need to use the `action`/`route` methods

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the PrintView method directly? I mean... why do you need to route all this data?